# Switching form tabs represented by <li>

Tags: jquery, iterator

I've made some form tabs using block-displayed list items.
Then I also have next and previous buttons, `$('#wiznext')` and `$('#wizprev')`.
Whenever next is clicked, the next list element in the tab list is selected, and the appropriate things are done.

The HTML is something like this:

```
<ul id='tabs'>
<li> Tab 1 </li>
<li> Tab 2 </li>
...
```

The jquery is like this:

```
$('#wizprev').click(function(){
   switchTab($current.prev('li').attr('id'));
 }
```

However I want to put a condition, i.e. don't switch the tab if there is no previous list item. So if the user is already on Tab 1, then hitting `previous` shouldn't do anything.

I'm doing this:
I tried this condition but it doesn't make a difference:

```
if($current.prev('li').length>0)
            switchTab($current.prev('li').attr('id'));
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: this `if($current.prev('li').length>0)` should work. Check what is returned

Comment: Okay it turned out it was working after all.

Answer (score 0):

Use if you check if there next

```
var next = $('#your-selector').next().length;

if(next == 0)
{ 
    return false;
} else {
    // do stuff
}
```

Use if you check if there a previous item

```
var prev = $('#your-selector').prev().length;

if(prev == 0)
{ 
    return false;
} else {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep some sort of counting variable, which will increment or decrement as the user clicks previous or next. Something like this:

```
var tabCounter = 1;
$('#wizprev').click(function(){
    if(tabCounter > 1) {
        tabCounter--;
        switchTab($current.prev('li').attr('id'));
    }
}

$('#wiznext').click(function() {
    if(tabCounter < $('#current li').length) {
        tabCounter++;
        switchTab($current.next('li').attr('id'));
    }
});
```

Something like this, keep a track of the tab number and don't do anything if the user is already on the first tab. Then check when going to the next tab that it isn't the last